# Problems with Seam 3 on WildFly 8 Final

Tags: java, jboss, seam, seam3, wildfly

I'm using WildFly 8 and I'm migrating my Java EE6 project to Java EE7 due to some WebSocket stuff.

In Maven, I use the following BOMs...

- org.wildfly.bom:jboss-javaee-7.0-with-tools:8.0.0.Final
- org.wildfly.bom:jboss-javaee-7.0-with-hibernate:8.0.0.Final
- org.jboss.seam:seam-bom:3.1.0.Final

And I get the following Exception on deployment:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalArgumentException: WELD-000818: Event type class org.jboss.solder.config.xml.bootstrap.ProcessAnnotatedTypeImpl is not allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling "legacy mode" for weld to be bit more relaxed about validation.
Open standalone.xml and edit weld subsystem configuration to:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:2.0" require-bean-descriptor="true" non-portable-mode="true" />
```

From documentation what this means:

```
<xs:attribute name="require-bean-descriptor" type="xs:boolean" default="false">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>If true then implicit bean archives without bean descriptor file (beans.xml) are ignored by Weld</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
<xs:attribute name="non-portable-mode" type="xs:boolean" default="false">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>If true then the non-portable mode is enabled. The non-portable mode is suggested by the specification to overcome problems with legacy applications that do not use CDI SPI properly and may be rejected by more strict validation in CDI 1.1.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
```